# WebGL corrupted context when the canvas size set in css

Tags: css, webgl

In a WebGL page when I hardcode the canvas size the good old way like 
 
    *<canvas id="main-canvas" width="800px" height="600px"> </canvas>*

 
everything looks great. But moving the size part to css produces very pixelated image, as it it was rendered in a very small size then magnified. I guess it is because I initialize webgl context upon the page load but the css takes effect a bit later so the webgl thinks that the control is smaller than it really is. Whether my guess is right or wrong how do I fix it ?

Answer (score 3):

I managed to fix this with the following code just before initializing the webgl context.

```
canvas.width = canvas.clientWidth;
canvas.height = canvas.clientHeight;
this.gl = canvas.getContext("webgl"); 
...
```

So it looks WebGL initiallizes the context based on the width and height while arguably it should do it on the client sizes.

Comment: No, it can't do it on client sizes. Canvas works the same as Images and Video. The size of the content is separate from the size you ask it to be displayed. canvas.width and canvas.height (or <canvas width="xxx" height="xxx">) define the size of the content. CSS defines the size that content is displayed.